# Supersized plugin shows up behind body background

Tags: jquery, css, background, supersized

Having an issue with the Supersized jQuery plugin on my website, I have the plugin working fine, but none of the images show up. They seem to be stuck 'behind' the body background.

This is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DSW5X/ I've validated the html and the css, nothing was apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add css rule:

```
body {background:transparent !important;}
```

Is this what you mean? [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ed9Xr/)

Comment: No problem, fellow Calgarian :D